# SQL Server : LAG in View - slow performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to use `LAG` in a SQL Server view. The performance of the view is horrible after I added the `LAG` function.

Please note the tables used in the view have millions of rows.

So instead of using view, I am now using a SQL function to do filtering (by passing in parameters) and do the `LAG`, and the performance is now perfect.

However, I am still interested in using `LAG` in the view, can you suggest how it should be done without having performance problem?

Example of the join:

```
SELECT
    a.TransactionID,
    LAG(dateadd(day, 1, a.TransDate), 1, '1990-01-01') OVER (PARTITION BY a.TransactionGroup ORDER BY a.TransDate) as PreviousTransDate
FROM
    dbo.Transactions a    -- millions of records
JOIN
    dbo.Names b ON a.NameId = b.NameId
WHERE
    b.NameId = @NameId    -- used in SQL function
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you show the definition of the view that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding indices on the following two columns:

- TransactionGroup
- TransDate

This should speed up your call to `LAG`, since it will be easier to partition, and then order, the data.

Also, your call to `LAG` looks a bit strange to me.  I think it should be this:

```
DATEADD(day, 1, LAG(a.TransDate, 1, '1990-01-01') OVER
    (PARTITION BY a.TransactionGroup ORDER BY a.TransDate))
```

In other words, first take the lag of the `TransDate` column, given some conditions, and then add one day to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't help. Making reasonable assumptions, it can be simplified to:

```
Select  t.TransactionID,
        LAG(dateadd(day, 1, t.TransDate), 1, '1990-01-01') OVER (PARTITION BY t.TransactionGroup ORDER BY t.TransDate) as PreviousTransDate
from dbo.Transactions t 
where t.NameId = @NameId -- Used in SQL Function
```

This, in turn, simply needs an index on `Transactions(NameId, TransactionGroup, TransDate)` for the best performance.

If I had to speculate, you have a view that has the `select` and `from`, but the `where` is in the outer query. The issue could be optimization. However, the two versions of the query would not be the same thing -- so the real issue is probably a logic problem.